# Formating dates with SQLite and SQLAlchemy query to get Month and Year for ploting graphs

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to format a datetime in SQLAlchemy like I can do in pure MYSQL:

```
DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m')
```

However, I am using SQLite as a database and would like to use SQLAlchemy rather than RAW sql code.

I understand that func.date() would turn the datetime into a date with SQLite and SQLAlchemy, but I need to get the year and month only like you can with:

```
func.to_char(datetime, '%Y-%m')
```

However, this only seems to work with PostgreSQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that the following works for SQLite with sqlalchemy:

```
func.strftime('%Y-%m', datetime)
```